# Toggle one element in React.js onClick

Tags: reactjs, toggle

I have info button that is supposed to open specific description element onclick event - info is obtained from Firebase. However, myOnclick event triggers all of the siblings elements and I need to toggle/untoggle only specific one. What am I missing and doing wrong?

here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import firebase from "../../firebase";
```

//Data obtained from DB and rendered on page

```
export default class Tour extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tours: [],
      showInfo: false,
    };
  }
```

// button that toggles info

```
   handleInfo = () => {
        this.setState({
          showInfo: !this.state.showInfo,
        });
      };
```

// component did mount

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();

    dbRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
      // checking changes in db
      const data = snapshot.val();
      const newToursAarray = [];

      for (let inventoryName in data) {
        const toursObject = {
          id: inventoryName,
          tours: data[inventoryName],
          name: data[inventoryName].name,
          seats: data[inventoryName].seats,
          date: data[inventoryName].date,
          duration: data[inventoryName].duration,
          imgUrl:"https://source.unsplash.com/350x350/?" + data[inventoryName].name,
          // temporary tour info placeholder and will be removed and connetcted to real DB
          info: "Lorem ipsum dolora saepe fugiat. " +
            data[inventoryName].name,
        };
        newToursAarray.push(toursObject);
      }

      this.setState({
        tours: newToursAarray,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tourlist">
        {this.state.tours.map((toursObject) => {
          return (
            <section className="tourItem">
              <header>
                <h3> {toursObject.name} </h3>
                <h5>
                  info
                  {/* button that toggles info */}
                  <span onClick={this.handleInfo}>
                    <i className="fas fa-caret-square-down"></i>
                  </span>
                </h5>
              </header>
              <ul className="inventoryItem" key={toursObject.id}>
                <li> {toursObject.date} |</li>
                <li>{toursObject.duration} hrs |</li>
                <li> {toursObject.seats} seats </li>
              </ul>
              <div className="img-container">
                {this.state.showInfo && (
                  // text that toggles when clicking on info button
                  <p className="tour-info">{toursObject.info}</p>
                )}
                <img src={toursObject.imgUrl} alt="image of the tour" />
             
              </div>
            </section>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here is that the expanding options are all referencing the same piece of state. You have your `state.showInfo` outside of your `tours.map`. So as you map through your tours, you say "if 'showInfo' then reveal this section" and that 'showInfo' is the same for everything.

What I would recommend is storing the `id` of the expanded tourObject, and then you can check against that.

Something like this:

```
handleInfo = (id) => {
  this.setState({
    infoToShow: id,
  });
};
```

And then in your `onClick` it would look more like this:

```
<span onClick={() => this.handleInfo(tourObject.id)}>
  <i className="fas fa-caret-square-down"></i>
</span>
```

And your logic to show or hide can just be this:

```
{this.state.infoToShow === tourObject.id && (
  // text that toggles when clicking on info button
  <p className="tour-info">{toursObject.info}</p>
)}
```

This way you can store the id in a place accessible to all the looped through tours, but they won't conflict with each other.

So instead of checking if `showInfo` is true, check if the `id` that you want to show matches the id of the tour.

Comment: ah, I see .Thank you soo much!

Comment: @SergeChurkin no problem, if this helped you out, I'd really appreciate if you could accept and upvote this answer. Thanks